# Find all files based on a list of file names / patterns

Tags: grep, find, sed

Say I have a list of keywords:

```
$ cat filenames.txt 
satin
perdido
savoy
stockings
april
lullabye
```

I want to find all the files in some directory that contains those keywords.

I have tried something like:

```
find some_dir/ -type f "$(printf '-or -iname *%s* ' $(cat filenames.txt))"
```

But somehow I am not able to use printf to build the whole find command; I get:

```
-bash: printf: -o: invalid option
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to list files that are _named_ `satin` etc. or that _contain the text_ `satin` etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I realize it was unclear. I want to find all files whose file NAME is a string that contains one of the keywords...

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command does not search the files' content.

The `-iname` option selects the filenames.

The error means that `printf` does not reconize the `-o` option. In such situation you should use `printf -- '-o...`

I think the final filter you are looking for is:

```
find some_dir/ -type f \( -iname \*satin\* -o -iname \*perdido\* ... \)
```

Note the `\( ... \)` to enclose all the `-iname ...`

`-o ...` is said to be POSIX in the `man find`

You need to be sure that the `filenames.txt` file contains at least one value.

If you need to find the filenames in the `some_dir/`, then give a try to this:

```
set -f ; find some_dir/ -type f \( $(printf -- ' -o -iname *%s*' $(cat filenames.txt)| cut -b4-) \) ; set +f
```

Comment: Your last command is what I am looking for thanks! But adding the keyword "artistry" to filenames.txt should have at least returned to me the file "01 Stan Kenton - Artistry In Rythm.flac" present in one of the subfolders of some_dir. But it didn't...

Comment: @fricadelle: true! , the command had been updated. A possible solution is to deactivate glob to avoid filename expansion with `set -f ; find ... ; set +f`.

Comment: I think I'd use an array - for example `mapfile -t filenames < filenames.txt` and then `find . \( -false $(printf -- ' -o -iname *%s*' "${filenames[@]}") \)` (note the `-false` dummy predicate that allows us to start the list with a `-o`)

Comment: @steeldriver: super! thx for the info